# c# XNA content file not found after changing build action

Tags: c#, xna, xap

I'm just about ready to submit my very first game to the marketplace but i ran into this problem.

I realized today that my XAP file seemed reallly small. (350kb roughly)
I was reading today that all my content (textures, sounds, fonts) should have their build actions set to "content" rather than "compile" which they were previously set to.
I set them all to the "content" setting and now I'm getting "Error loading "filename". File not found."

I didn't change ANYTHING else but the build action and I've confirmed that all the files are not found.
Is there something i need to change in my load statements after changing the build action?
Currently my load statements look like these.

`font = content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont");`

or

`ShipTexture = ScreenManager.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Jet");`

fyi I've built my game from the ground up using the GameStateManagement sample, in case that matters.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read that, but it's not true.

The `ContentManager` object, like `Game.Content`, is programmed to look for `xnb` files. Those have to be *compiled* from source files, like .png's, .wav's, etc. Setting to `Content` copies the source files over directly into the XAP, and you must thus open it with `TitleContainer.OpenStream` to use it, instead of the normal `Content.Load`, because it will not be an `xnb` file.

If your XAP file is curiously small, it is probably because XAPs use ZIP compression on the entire package. Check out your "Content" folder in your bin\Debug or bin\Release folder to see the full size, uncompressed.

Answer (score 1):

You want it set to `Compile`, not `Content`. `Build Action: Compile` means that it will be processed as XNA content into an `.xnb` file which is then accessible from a `ContentManager.Load<T>` call. `Build Action: Content` is something else which does not result in your content being compiled. It's either just copied straight over, or ignored, but either way the asset won't be available from the `ContentManager`.

Comment: so having it set to compile is fine when submitting my XAP file to the marketplace?  as i said before the XAP seemed realllly small.